# vboxmanage guestcontrol change password

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualhost, virtualbox-guest-additions

I have a script that inside a virtual machine I'm able to trigger.

However, I'd like to pass the argument to the script. I'd normally run the script as ">>test.bat user1"

The arguement is "user1". Can someone help modify the below command to pass the arguement?

```
VBoxManage --nologo guestcontrol "sample1" run --exe "C:\Users\sample1\Desktop\test.bat" --username sample1 --password sample2 --wait-stdout
```

I also tried running

```
VBoxManage --nologo guestcontrol "sample1" run --exe "C:\Users\sample1\Desktop\test.bat user1" --username sample1 --password sample2 --wait-stdout
```

But it was not right, I had results for above command as :

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage --nologo guestcontrol "sample3" run --exe "C:\Users\sample1\Desktop\test.bat user1"  --username sample1 --password sample2 --wait-stdout
VBoxManage.exe: error: No such file or directory on guest
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005), component GuestProcessWrap, interface IGuestProcess, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "WaitForArray(ComSafeArrayAsInParam(aWaitStartFlags), gctlRunGetRemainingTime(msStart, cMsTimeout), &waitResult)" at line 1485 of file VBoxManageGuestCtrl.cpp
```

Also tried

```
VBoxManage --nologo guestcontrol "sample1" run --exe "C:\Users\sample1\Desktop\test.bat" --username sample1 --password sample2 --wait-stdout --user1

 

Usage:

 

VBoxManage guestcontrol     <uuid|vmname> [--verbose|-v] [--quiet|-q]
                              [--username <name>] [--domain <domain>]
                              [--passwordfile <file> | --password <password>]
                              run [common-options]
                              [--exe <path to executable>] [--timeout <msec>]
                              [-E|--putenv <NAME>[=<VALUE>]] [--unquoted-args]
                              [--ignore-operhaned-processes] [--profile]
                              [--no-wait-stdout|--wait-stdout]
                              [--no-wait-stderr|--wait-stderr]
                              [--dos2unix] [--unix2dos]
                              -- <program/arg0> [argument1] ... [argumentN]]

 

VBoxManage.exe: error: Unknown option: --user1
```

Comment: Can you try `VBoxManage --nologo guestcontrol "sample1" run --exe "C:\Users\sample1\Desktop\test.bat" --username sample1 --password sample2 --wait-stdout user1`

Comment: @MatzZze 

I tried you comment. It results in 
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage --nologo guestcontrol "sample3" run --exe "C:\Users\sample1\Desktop\test.bat"  --username sample1 --password sample2 --wait-stdout user1
'user1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file

Comment: And what is the result if you pass the user1 arg to the --exe command like this: `VBoxManage --nologo guestcontrol "sample1" run --exe "C:\Users\sample1\Desktop\test.bat user1" --username sample1 --password sample2 --wait-stdout`

Comment: @MatzZze Please check the updated question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From VBoxManage doc:

```
VBoxManage guestcontrol <uuid|vmname> run [common-options] --exe <path to executable> 
[--timeout <msec>] [-E|--putenv <NAME>[=<VALUE>]] [--unquoted-args]
[--ignore-operhaned-processes] [--profile] [--no-wait-stdout|--wait-stdout]
[--no-wait-stderr|--wait-stderr] [--dos2unix] [--unix2dos] -- <program/arg0> [argument1] ... [argumentN]]
```

Please try

```
VBoxManage --nologo guestcontrol "sample1" run --exe "C:\Users\sample1\Desktop\test.bat" --username sample1 --password sample2 --wait-stdout -- user1
```

I was missing the `--` in my previous comment

Comment: It resulted in
`VBoxManage.exe: error: Unknown option: --user1`

Comment: eww... Next attempt: `VBoxManage --nologo guestcontrol "sample1" run --username sample1 --password sample2 --wait-stdout -- "C:\Users\sample1\Desktop\test.bat" user1`

Comment: oh there has to be a space between the `--` and `user1`

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, this question has nothing to do with vboxmanage, and is simply a question of how to pass a reference a command line parameter within a batch file.

Within the batch file, the command line parameters are referenced as %1, %2, %3, etc. in the order they are presented on the command line.  Thus:

Here's a simple, one-line bat file, named doit.bat

```
echo %1 %2 %3
```

And here's its execution:

```
C:\>doit firstparm secondparm thirdparm

C:\>echo firstparm secondparm thirdparm
firstparm secondparm thirdparm
```

Comment: I think you've got me wrong. I'm trying to execute the batch script outside the guest vm.

The following command would not work

`VBoxManage --nologo guestcontrol "sample1" run --exe "C:\Users\sample1\Desktop\test.bat user1" --username sample1 --password sample2 --wait-stdout`

Comment: Well, you _did_ say 'However, I'd like to pass the argument to the script. I'd normally run the script as ">>test.bat user1"   ... The arguement is "user1". Can someone help modify the below command to pass the arguement?"   I see that your update and all subsequent discussion has nothing to do with passing an argument and everything to do with vboxmanage syntax. ;-)